# How to solve $x^3 = 3$ (mod $257)$ while knowing that $3$ is a primitive root mod $257$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

We were given the hint that $3$ is a primitive root of unity, meaning that for all $y$ such that $\gcd(y,257)=1$, we can find a power $k$ such that $3^k \equiv y$  (mod $257)$. But I have no idea how to deal with the third power in my equation.

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Serious question: Why did my question get downvoted so heavily? I tried to mention everything I knew/tried for this problem, so I do not quite understand.

Comment: Because it is a "I'm clueless" question."  It reads like you are expecting this site to "do your work for you."  That's not the pupose of this site.  Please carefully read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|132.0253).  We want askers to *participate* when asking their questions.  There's no fault in not knowing; we merely expect users to help us help them as best we can, without having to guess, or read the minds of askers.

Comment: I see your point, thank you. It was definitely not my expection that others do my whole work. I would have been happy about some hints already. Maybe I should have worded my question better - I will be more careful next time. Hopefully, the guide you provided will help me with that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x < 257$, then we know that $\gcd(x,257) = 1$. So there exist a $k$ such that $x = 3^k \mod 257$. Then $x^{3} = 3^{3k} \mod 257 =3$.

Thus, $3^{3k-1} = 1 \mod 257$.

Since $257$ is prime and $3$ is primitive root of it, we should have $3k = 1 \mod 256$. We can easily find that $k = 171$, so $x = 3^{171} = 147 \mod 257$

Comment: Can I assume $\gcd(x,257)=1$ because $\gcd(3,257)=1$?

Comment: @ Diglett we can consider $x < 257$ since $257$ is prime.

Comment: what does the equation has to do with primitive root?

Answer (score 0):

If $3$ is a primitive root then $x \equiv 3^k$ or some integer $k$. And as $257$ is prime $3^{256} \equiv 1$ and $3^m \equiv 3 \pmod{257}\iff m\equiv 1 \pmod {256}$.

So we have $x^3 \equiv (3^k)^3 \equiv 3^{3k} \equiv 3 \pmod {257}$ so

$3k \equiv 1 \pmod {256}$.  So there is an $m$ so that $3k = 1 + 256m$.  But as $256\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ $m = 2$ will do it.  $3k \equiv 1 + 256\cdot 2\equiv 513 \pmod {256}$ and $k \equiv 171\pmod{256}$.

And $x \equiv 3^{171}\pmod {257}$.

Answer (score 0):

$3^{256}\equiv 1 \bmod 257$

$\Rightarrow 3^{128}\equiv 1\bmod 257$

multiplying both sides by 3 we get:

$3^{129=3\times 43}=(3^{43})^3\equiv 3\bmod 257$

$\Rightarrow x=3^{43}$